# Error on adding jsreport report template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, jsreport

I am getting the following error on adding jsreport report template in Visual Studio 2015. I searched online for the error, however I couldnt find anything related to this so far. Any help will be much appreciated.[Error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GxRo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsreport visual studio extension and jsrep report templates are no longer supported. You should use native templates format used by jsreport and use the html based studio to preview the reports.

Please read the updated docs
http://jsreport.net/learn/net-embedded